# Collapsing toolbar layout with recyclerview need to collapse based on recycler view height

Tags: java, android

I have a collapsing toolbar layout and a recycler `

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profileHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/user_pic_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/user_pic_height"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/user_pic_margin"
                    android:alpha="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder_profile_rect"
                    app:siBorderAlpha="@dimen/user_pic_border_alpha"
                    app:siBorderColor="@color/colorTransparentLight"
                    app:siBorderWidth="@dimen/user_pic_border_width"
                    app:siRadius="@dimen/user_pic_border_radius" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        app:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Addresss of the person"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        app:textStyle="light" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gift"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_gift" />

            <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.TextView
                android:id="@+id/giftText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGift" />

            <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.ExpandableLayout
                android:id="@+id/friendExpandableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:el_contentLayout="@layout/layout_my_friends"
                app:el_headerLayout="@layout/layout_header" />

            <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.ExpandableLayout
                android:id="@+id/memoryExpandableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                app:el_contentLayout="@layout/layout_my_memories"
                app:el_headerLayout="@layout/layout_header" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

In the above code behaves like collapsing toolbar layout collapse its data always even the recycler view data is empty,But i need it like it should collapse upto the recycler view height.

`

Comment: If i understood your question clearly, you can use `android:minHeight`